# How to get next maximum number from datatable

Tags: c#, .net

I have a datatable filled from database. in this datatable there's a column name "TabOrder"
Now i want to loop through this datatable and get next max taborder than current iteration of loop. For example if current iteration (i) of loop is 5, i want next maximum number from taborder column. next max could be 6, 7, 10 etc

```
    for (int j = 0; j < dtFormFields.Rows.Count; j++)
                            {
                                if (dtFormFields.Rows[j]["taborder"].ToString() == (tabOrder + 1).ToString())
                                {
                                    foreach (var control in objForm.Controls)
                                    {
                                        if (control is GroupControl)
                                        {
                                            var objGroupControl = control as GroupControl;
                                            foreach (var ctrl in objGroupControl.Controls)
                                            {
                                                if (ctrl is TextEdit)
                                                {
                                                    var objTextBox = ctrl as TextEdit;
                                                    if (objTextBox.Name == dtFormFields.Rows[j]["textboxname"].ToString())
                                                    {
                                                        ReturnControl = objTextBox;
                                                        objTextBox.TabIndex = tabOrder;
                                                        break;
                                                    }
                                                }
}
}
}
}
}
```

i want to set next max taborder of current control. How to accomplish this.

Comment: You will need to explain in much more detail what you are trying to do, and what you have done so far to achieve it. Post some code, and the manual sections you have read, and why they didn't help you.

Comment: i have edited my question. pasted code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have understood is; the TabOrder column contains values and while iterating there are chances that the column may have higher value than the one you have at current iteration. 
1. You can achieve this at the time of filling your DataTable from database. So if your query sorts the data on TabOrder, you will get the next value. (But this may fail when say a number 5 is there for multiple times.)
2. Inside your loop call a simple function and send the current TabOrder value and loop through the DataTable column values again to get the next max number.

Let me know if this helps or provide more information.

Comment: i dont want to loop again.

Comment: Your first suggestion is helpful. Solved my problem. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Let `dtTable` be the dataTable which is being populated from the database and are having a column named  `TabOrder`. then the following code will help you to order these rows in the order of `TabOrder` and take the row having the second highest row order

```
 var secondMaxRow = dtTable.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x["TabOrder"]).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```